# Where do the module and inject jasmine functions come from?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I keep seeing jasmine specs testing angular controllers/directives/filters employing these two functions but where do they come from? Where can I find their documentations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both come from Angular itself:

- [Angular.Mock.Inject documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)
- [Angular.Mock.Module documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module)

I believe both are defined in angular-mocks.js, which puts module and inject as properties on window.